# SOQL query to retrieve records

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

I need to query an object called trans__c which has the following fields

```
 id,
 scantime__c // datetime
 name
 asset__c // external id
 status
```

I need to get only data which has status as pending and if there are any repeating asset then I need to get only record with scantime as the latest.

For e.g.

If there are 3 records

```
   asset         name      scantime              Status

    1            Rec 1      17-dec-2011 13:10     Pending
    1            Rec2       17-dec-2011 13:50     Pending
    2            Rec3       17-dec-2011 13:10     Pending
```

The output of the query should be

```
    1            Rec2       17-dec-2011 13:50     Pending
    2            Rec3       17-dec-2011 13:10     Pending
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group By is only really for use with aggregate queries, which is a bit of a pain when it comes to the other fields that you don't want to aggregate.

This may not be the correct approach, but I'd grab all of the 'Pending' records then do the logic in code (assuming you're not masses of results):

```
map<integer, Trans__c> mapAssetToRecord = new map<integer, Trans__c>();

for(Trans__c [] sTransArr : [select Id, Name, Asset__c, Scan_Time__c, Status__c
                               from Trans__c
                              where Status__c = 'Pending'])
{
    for(Trans__c sTrains : sTransArr)
    {
        if(mapAssetToRecord.get(sTrans.Asset__c) == null)
        {
            mapAssetToRecord.put(sTrans.Asset__c, sTrans);
        }
        else if(sTrans.Scan_Time__c > mapAssetToRecord.get(sTrans.Asset__c).Scan_Time__c)
        {
            mapAssetToRecord.put(sTrans.Asset__c, sTrans);
        }
    }
}

// now mapAssetToRecord includes all of the records you want
```

There may be a more elegant solution involving some clever SOQL, but it escapes me right now (after all, it is Sunday morning and I've only just had breakfast!).

Comment: I believe that after doing a GROUP BY on Id it will pull all records that aren't in the aggregate function since Id is unique. So a call to MAX() and then doing a GROUP BY on all other fields beginning with Id should pull all necessary records (all that have the max value specified - datetime in this case). At least that's how it's behaving in my schema browser :)

Comment: On second thought, you may be right. Aggregate queries in SOQL are a bit confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I pretty much never find them useful unless I actually want to do sum, count or average!

Answer (score 1):

Your query will look like this:

```
SELECT Id, MAX(scantime__c), Name, asset__c, status
FROM trans__c WHERE status = 'Pending' 
GROUP BY Id, Name, asset__c, status
```

Cheers

[EDIT]

Looks like the aggregate query will return additional rows that you want omitted so perhaps what Lacey is suggesting will work better for you. But aggregates *can* be really useful when appropriately applied. Good luck.

Comment: I actually created the object to play around with this, even using `GROUP BY` (and putting `Asset__s` first) I still get 3 records returned because we also have to group by Name and Id if we want those fields returned in the query.